# How to get list of languages and input languages in android

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

How do i get the following lists in code?

First one is the OS langauge as i see it in my device language setting

[image: OS language]

The second one is the keyboard input languages

[image: keyboard input language]

When i use `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` i get list with 600 results. 
When i open language selection i see 100 results in list.(Screenshot1)
When i open keyboard languages selection i see 200 results in list.(Screenshot2)
How the OS filter those 600 result to get 100 and 200 lists?
How can i do that?

Comment: @DerGolem That not what i am asking and if you read the question you can see that i stated that Locale.getAvailableLocales() is not what i need.

Comment: Then tell me which other method you'd like to use, I'm curious.

Comment: That's exactly what i asked. How they populate those list when choosing languages and how i can do it.

Comment: @DerGolem And that a great idea to close question when you don't know the answer.

Comment: I **know** the answer. But you don't accept it. So, **for me**, the question is closed. Also notice that you need **5** votes to close a question. So mine is only a mere **20%**. Maybe, your post will remain open?

Comment: I don't see any code that answers my question..
I will pin my question in minute that will differ from the "duplicate"

Answer (score 1):

According to [Android source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/com/android/internal/app/LocalePicker.java#LocalePicker), this is how the locales are retrieved:

```
Resources.getSystem().getAssets().getLocales();
```

Also note that the code I linked does a number of checks to build the list that gets actually displayed so you might need to go through it to get the exact same result.

Comment: The code you linked is how to get result of screenshot1 or screenshot2 ?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure. It might be a generic `LocalePicker` used across the `Settings` part of Android.